# Produce csv from ps output

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Looking for a way to parse output of ps command so can send it to a spreadsheet for some analysis.

```
ps x --sort -rss -o pid,pcpu,pmem,vsz,rss,uname,cmd,start
```

Looking for a way to specify a separator for each field